ASAN does not detect buffer overflow
There is the following piece of code
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
thread_local std::aligned_storage_t<1024> data;
int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
    uint8_t * d = new (&data) uint8_t[1024];
    d[1025] = '6';
    std::cout << d[1025] << std::endl;
}

Sanitiser does not detect buffer overflow
Code sample
https://godbolt.org/z/r34f9jexj

You don't need the placement-new, this reproduces on a plain array: https://godbolt.org/z/Y5Pc3TKvT (on both Clang and GCC). Interestingly, I can also repro on non-thread-local array (but only on GCC, Clang catches this one). I'd report this as a bug to ASAN.

ASAN needs to be instrument specifically for container types. There is, for example, a special implementation for std::vector in ASAN: std::vector will often allocate more memory than immediately needed to store the data (see .capacity()), and ASAN has code in there to still figure out that the read/write was out of bounds of the vector. My guess is that ASAN doesn't yet have special handling code for aligned_storage_t, which is why it's likely it doesn't find the error in your case.

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/12

@chris_se My understanding is that it should do the right thing by default. std::vector needs manual instrumentation only because you want to catch out-of-bounds accesses that are not outside the capacity (which isn't inherenrly illegal from ASAN's point of view).

undefined catches it https://godbolt.org/z/TTrW1oYK3

It looks like sanitisation of thread_local global variables hasn't been implemented yet https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/12
